# Dropdown filters for plotly dashboard

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have this dataset below and this code that outputs this chart

| Column A | Tools | Category | role | figure | Occurences After | idx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PostgreSQL | DatabaseHaveWorkedWith | Developer, front-end | 38.044286 | 4 | False |
| 1 | MySQL | DatabaseHaveWorkedWith | Developer, front-end | 45.883489 | 2 | False |
| 0 | MongoDB | DatabaseWantToWorkWith | Developer, front-end | 39.018110 | 1 | True |
| 1 | PostgreSQL | DatabaseWantToWorkWith | Developer, front-end | 48.236203 | 3 | False |
| 0 | MySQL | DatabaseHaveWorkedWith | Developer, back-end | 26.096002 | 1 | True |
| 1 | PostgreSQL | DatabaseHaveWorkedWith | Developer, back-end | 33.771734 | 2 | False |
| 0 | Redis | DatabaseWantToWorkWith | Developer, back-end | 28.495408 | 1 | True |
| 1 | PostgreSQL | DatabaseWantToWorkWith | Developer, back-end | 40.314136 | 1 | True |

```py
from itertools import cycle
import plotly.express as px
fig = go.Figure()

palette = cycle(px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet)
colors = {c:next(palette) for c in daata['Tools'].values}
#Build dropdown Labels
labels = daata['role'].unique()

for i, row in daata.iterrows():
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(x=[[row['role']],[row["Category"]]],
            y=[row["figure"]],
            name=row["Tools"],
            text=str(round(row["figure"],2))+'%', showlegend=row['idx'],marker_color=colors[row["Tools"]],
            legendgroup=row["Tools"]# Fix legend
            ))

fig.update_layout({
   'barmode': 'group',
    'xaxis': {
        'tickangle': -45,
    },
    'yaxis': {
        'title_text': "figures",
    },
})
fig.show()
```

The above code outputs this chart

[image: chart]

However, I want to also add a dropdown filter for the roles (i.e the chart can be filtered by 'Developer, back-end', 'Developer, front-end' and 'All'

I have tried adding button labels, all what have tried kept filtering the chart wrongly

Answer (score 0):

With dash you can add Dropdown and then use value to return fig. Please check below code:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, dash_table, Input, Output, callback
import plotly.express as px
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle


palette = cycle(px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet)
colors = {c:next(palette) for c in daata['Tools'].values}
#Build dropdown Labels
labels = daata['role'].unique()
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout = html.Div([
     dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown',
                  options=[
                      {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df['role'].unique()],
                         value=[],
                         multi=True,
                         disabled=False,
                         clearable=True,
                         searchable=True),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph',figure={})
])

@app.callback(Output('graph','figure'),
              Input('dropdown','value'))
def update_graph(role):
    if role == []:
        dff= daata.copy()
        fig = go.Figure()
        for i, row in dff.iterrows():
            fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(x=[[row['role']],[row["Category"]]],
            y=[row["figure"]],
            name=row["Tools"],
            text=str(round(row["figure"],2))+'%', showlegend=row['idx'],marker_color=colors[row["Tools"]],
            legendgroup=row["Tools"]# Fix legend
            ))

            fig.update_layout({
                'barmode': 'group',
                'xaxis': {'tickangle': -45},
                'yaxis': {'title_text': "figures",},
            })
    else:
        dff= daata[daata['role'].isin(role)]
        fig = go.Figure()
        for i, row in dff.iterrows():
            fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(x=[[row['role']],[row["Category"]]],
            y=[row["figure"]],
            name=row["Tools"],
            text=str(round(row["figure"],2))+'%', showlegend=row['idx'],marker_color=colors[row["Tools"]],
            legendgroup=row["Tools"]# Fix legend
            ))

            fig.update_layout({
                'barmode': 'group',
                'xaxis': {'tickangle': -45},
                'yaxis': {'title_text': "figures",},
            })
    return fig

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Hope this help
[image]

Comment: thank you, this helps but the legend is incomplete, for example 'Developer, front- end'  the legend only shows 'MongoDB'

Comment: @GodsfavourOluwajobaOluwabori: I think problem come from `showlegend=row['idx']`.